# XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I am using Google matrix api in angularjs  like below code :

```
 var params = {origins: $scope.getrest.origin, destinations: addr, key: 'AIzaSyAfkiSErIwa6AGNYmig'};

return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json', {params: params}).then(function (res) {
```

});

but it gives me error show in image and i also include js file and also try all solution from google but not find any proper solutions.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szZ5z.jpg)

Comment: seems you are using cross domain ,you need jSONP or  $http.jsonp, also check whether sever grant access or not

Comment: i tried all this thing but same error

Answer (score 0):

Make the request to googleapis server side to avoid the X domain origin rule (e.g. if you are using Java in your backend make the request there) then your front end code can easily access that data